# Can't move file notifications

Tags: macos, permission, google-apps

I'm getting the following Google Drive notifications pop up (Mac running Ventura 13.3), which is happening every few minutes and annoying me.

I can't find the files in question on my drive, nor do I want any sort of access to them, I just want these notifications gone. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I am using the same version and also have Google Drive for Mac, but I have not encountered this issue. Look at the software that runs in the background, it might be possible that there is something not directly related to Google Drive that is trying to move files. Also, check the synchronization settings. It's possible that Google Drive for Mac on your device is syncing something from a location you're not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at your Mac's Time Machine settings. You probably want to exclude your Google Drive.

Comment: How does this answer the question? How would excluding Google Drive make the notification go away? Please be clearer and explain thoroughly your answer and how it appropriately responds to the question.

Comment: My suggestion to look at which folders are being excluded from Time Machine’s backup was based on another’s comment about considering what software is running in the background. Time Machine runs in the background. It backs up files. I thought it was worth a look to see if your Time Machine was trying to backup files on your Google Drive. That would be a needless thing to do. But if it were erroneously set up to do that, maybe it would account for the notification popups. Just an easy thing to check.

Comment: Okay, this should be asked as a comment then. It looks more like a question to the OP than a final answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, I would recommend asking this as a comment to the question. You could also include explanations *in* the answer, so it doesn't require clarifications. :)